# Xmonad gives a parse error where I used a snippet of a working configuration

Tags: haskell, vim, configuration, indentation, archlinux

I have just started using Xmonad and (of course) I ran into some errors I can't seem to fix. This config file is pretty small, as I do not really have the need for a lot of keybindings. I am configuring xmonad in an arch linux virtual machine, if it matters, I am using neovim to edit the file and I have copied the default config's indentation to try and fix the error myself. Thank you for any help you can give me.

Here is my config file:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Azerty
import Data.Monoid
import System.Exit

import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import qualified Data.Map        as M

myFocusFollowsMouse :: Bool
myFocusFollowsMouse = True

myClickJustFocuses :: Bool
myClickJustFocuses = False

myWorkspaces       = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

-- Some keybindings, it launches my terminal, dmenu and Firefox.

myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $


        -- launch the terminal
        [ ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_Return), spaw $ XMonad.terminal conf)

        -- launch dmenu
        , ((modm,               xK_p     ), spawn "dmenu_run")

        -- launch firefox
        , ((modm,               xK_f     ), spawn "firefox")

        -- close focused window
        , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_q     ), kill)

        -- restart xmonad
        , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_x     ), spawn "xmonad --recompile; xmonad --restart")
        ]
        ++

        [((m .|. modm, k), windows $ f i)
            | (i, k) <- zip (XMonad.workspaces conf) [xK_1 .. xK_9]
            , (f, m) <- [(W.greedyView, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)]]
        ++


        myMouseBindings (XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm})  M.fromList $

        [ ((modm, button1), (\w -> focus w >> mouseMoveWindow w
                                           >> windows W.shiftMaster))





main = xmonad defaults azertyConfig


defaults = def {

  borderWidth         = 2,
  terminal            = "xterm",
  normalBorderColor   = "#ededed",
  focusedBorderColor  = "#e60707",
  modMask             = mod1Mask,
  workspaces          = myWorkspaces,
  keys                = myKeys,
  mouseBindings       = myMouseBindings,
  focusFollowsMouse   = myFocusFollowsMouse,
  clickJustFocuses    = myClickJustFocuses

  }
```

And here is the error I get:

```
xmonad.hs:54:1 error:
    parse error (possible incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
    |
54  | main = xmonad defaults azertyConfig^M
    | ^
```

I already fixed all (I think?) errors regarding tabulations instead of spaces. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Are you sure there is no missing bracket, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive, I used the default xmonad config file to write that last bit because I was getting multiple errors.

Comment: You're missing a close bracket (`]`) at the end of your `myKeys` funciton.

Comment: ```myMouseBindings``` you mean?

Comment: @JohnTitor I suggest double-checking the config file you are using as a model. The first line of the `myMouseBindings` definition should not be indented and is missing an equals sign; also, the `++`  immediately before it shouldn't be there.